# Ubuntu 21.10 not using intel drivers for integrated graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, 21.10, integrated

I'm trying to get Ubuntu to play nicely with an SBC running an Intel Celeron N6211. I get the impression that ubuntu should be able to sort this out and use the i915 driver automatically, but for some reason it isn't.

Things I have tried/made sure of so far:

- The grub doesn't have nomodeset.
- Everything is up to date.
- Tried Driver as "modesetting" and "intel" (default) for integrated graphics section in /etc/X11/xorg.conf

If I do inxi -Fxxxa, under Graphics I get:

Graphics:
Device-1: Intel driver: N/A alternate: i915 bus-ID: 00:02.0
chip-ID: 8086:4555 class-ID: 0300
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 compositor: gnome-shell driver:
loaded: amdgpu,ati,fbdev,intel,modesetting,nouveau,radeon,vesa,vmware
display-ID: :1 screens: 1
Screen-1: 0 s-res: 800x600 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 212x159mm (8.3x6.3")
s-diag: 265mm (10.4")
Monitor-1: default res: 800x600 hz: 75
OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1 128 bits)
v: 4.5 Mesa 22.1.0-devel (git-cb29604 2022-02-15 impish-oibaf-ppa)
direct render: Yes

I'm not sure, but it seems like it recognises that it **could** use i915 (it's set as the alternate driver?) but there is no driver in use, hence N/A after 'driver:'. How can I force it to use the correct driver? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I think it's trying to use the right driver, here's the relevant part of my xorg.0.log: https://pastebin.com/Tb208MdE

> open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory

This catches my eye, but I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Yes, if correctly installed the open-source Intel Graphics driver should be selected, no user action required. Is it not a VM, is it? There's a mention of "vmware". And why are you using the Obaif PPA?

Comment: @ChanganAuto You mean is the chip an M? It's a celeron N6211. Presumably the vmware bit is just default? And I have no idea, I never told it to use the oibaf-ppa. Maybe because it's rendering on the cpu instead?

Comment: Sorry, typo (now corrected). The question was about a bare metal installation or a Virtual Machine, because of the "vmware" (In a virtualized environment you're expected to have virtual hardware, not the real one).  `Mesa 22.1.0-devel (git-cb29604 2022-02-15 impish-oibaf-ppa)` clearly shows it's the version from the Obaif PPA, not from the Ubuntu repositories so you must have added said PPA, there's no other way.

Comment: I've tried several things, maybe I just forgot doing a step that installed oibaf. I've now purged oibaf from root shell. Either way, ubuntu wasn't using the correct driver when it was first installed. I have tried generating a new xorg.conf, but get errors. Created a minimal config etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf that is basically the one answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505088/x-configure-doesnt-work-number-of-created-screens-does-not-match-number-of-d but now get a single underscore on a black background when booting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the support just isn't there. Switching to Ubuntu Core Desktop Intel IoT fixed the issue, as it has specific support for Elkhart graphics.